# Psexec - run command remotely and save output to local file

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I'm trying to run multiple commands remotely using psexec.

I launch psexec from a local computer then specify the remote computer to connect. 
I want to store the output of the remote command on my local pc that initiated the psexec command.

If use ">" or ">>" the file gets created on the remote pc, not on my local pc.

Here is the code that I use:

```
cmd /c "c:\windows\system32\psexec.exe" \\192.168.0.2 -accepteula -u test -p test -s cmd /k (date /t) ^& (time /t) ^& (hostname) ^& (wmic csproduct get name, identifyingnumber) ^& (net statistics workstation) ^& (wmic LOGICALDISK LIST BRIEF) ^& (echo.) ^& (net use) ^& (tasklist)'+' ^& (echo.) ^& (echo. LISTARE CONTINUT FISIER HOSTS:) ^& (type c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Certainly do not need to use CMD /C to start PSEXEC. Why don't you just put all those commands into a batch file, one line per command?,

Comment: And you can always redirect to the server `>>\\servername\sharename\folder\file.txt` - admins always have access to each harddrive via sharename `C$`. So `>>\\myComputer\C$\Folder\file.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how PSExec works, on the other computer. WMIC can do what you want all by itself.

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process get /format:list
```

or

```
wmic /node:@C:\folder\computerlist.txt process get /format:list
```

computerlist.txt looks like this

```
127.0.0.1
MyComputerName
168.0.0.1
```

so you can mix 'n match names or ip addresses.

or

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 /output:C:\folder\output.txt process get /format:list
```

Although wmic does do redirection. Use `Append` instead of `output` to append.

See `wmic /?`, `wmic /output /?`, and `wmic /format /?`.

Also wmic can run programs invisible on other computers.

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create notepad.exe
```

Because 127.0.0.1 is a local address you'll see notepad but won't see it on a remote computer. See `wmic process call create /?`

Comment: Thanks for posting this useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an async job that executes multiple instances of psexec and saves outputs locally see [Executing a batch file in a remote machine through PsExec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299830/executing-a-batch-file-in-a-remote-machine-through-psexec/39976095#39976095) for details